# R colorRampPalette

Tags: r, colorbar

I wanna ask about centering my color scale using colorramppalette and color brewer. I have an issue which that the 0 value is not on the center. Since my scale value are not symmetric and I am using red to blue color which i reversed. Maybe you guys have an idea how to fix it. Lot of thanks!

Script:

```
brks <- seq(-15,45,5)
length(brks)
colorscale <- rev(colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(11, "RdBu"))(25))

windows()
image.plot(lon,lat,t_slice,
           col=colorscale,breaks=brks,lab.breaks=brks,
           xaxt="n", yaxt="n", ann=FALSE)
map(database="world", add=TRUE)
graphics.off()
```

[image]

I'm expecting for solution to make the color scale blue if less than 0, and red if more than 0

Answer (score 0):

Since your breaks have length 13, a color scale vector of 13 color values should be sufficient. Can't test the whole setup so using a toy image.

```
library(RColorBrewer)

brks <- seq(-15,45,5)
colorscale <- c(rev(colorRampPalette(
                  c("white", brewer.pal(9, "Blues")))(which(brks == 0))),
  colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9, "Reds"))(length(brks) - which(brks == 0)))

image(as.matrix(1:length(brks)), col=colorscale)
```

[image]